# MVC: Controller or Repository with ModelState.Isvalid and DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, controller

Should ModelState.Isvalid and DbUpdateConcurrencyException be in the Controller or Repository? I created an MVC Core Project, conducted scaffolding on a table. However, scaffolding does not create interfaces or repositories, so for proper software design, placed the insert/update code in Repository.

Just inquiring if the ModelState.IsValid and DbUpdateConcurrencyException  should also be placed in repository? I receive compile errors if placing in repository. I am new to software design and MVC, still learning.

**Controller**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Update(ProductTransaction);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {                    
         if (!ProductTransactionExists(ProductTransaction.Id))
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
         else
         {
             throw;
         }
```

**Repository**

```
ProductTransaction.Id= ProductTransactionViewModel.Id;
ProductTransaction.Date= ProductTransactionViewModel.Date
ProductTransaction.CustomerName = ProductTransactionViewModel.CustomerName
```

Comment: `ModelState` is a property of `Controller`, and its value is set by the `Controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should ModelState.Isvalid and DbUpdateConcurrencyException be in the
>   Controller or Repository? I created an MVC Core Project, conducted
>   scaffolding on a table.

`ModelState.IsValid` belong to the presentation layer it should stay there. If its value is `true` you should return the same view manipulated by the user before he submited it.

`DbUpdateConcurrencyException` belongs to the repository layer and you must not propagate it to the presentation layer. You catch that exception when it occurs. You log the relevant details about it. After that you throw a custom excpetion, `BusinessException` for example, that contains only message that user can understand like "*Someone already modified the content. So refresh to view it*". The presentation layer only knows about `BusinessException` and how to read its message.